# Best option to load react intersection observer : Parent or child component?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I'm using Gatsby to build my website, and React Intersection Observer to trigger animation with useInView. However, I would have question that may sounds dumb but I'm new with React.

I got several child components that uses React Intersection and I'm wondering what is the best option :

1/ Import useInView in each component that uses it likes this

```
import React from "react";
import ChildComponent1 from "folder";
import ChildComponent2 from "folder";

const ParentComponent = ({ data }) => {
//Import useInView inside each child component
return (
<ChildComponent1/>
<ChildComponent2/>
)}
```

2/ Import in the parent component and pass it to the child components as props

```
import React from "react";
import ChildComponent1 from "folder";
import ChildComponent2 from "folder";
import { useInView } from "react-intersection-observer";

const ParentComponent = ({ data }) => {
//Import useInView inside each child component
return (
<ChildComponent1 prop={useInView} />
<ChildComponent2 prop={useInView} />
)}
```

Which option is the best ?

Thanks a lot